# How to serve raster mosaic to AutoCad Map 3D from ArcGIS Server without its Image extension?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-server, autocad-map

We are looking for a way to serve all the raster datasets we've collected over the years as a mosaic we have built in ArcGIS so that the AutoCAD department can simply import the mosaic and it will show the raster data in the location they are working. We have ArcGIS Server and ArcSDE.

Has anyone accomplish this?

We would prefer to do this without purchasing the ArcGIS Image Service extension.

Comment: I will look into it. I am almost sure the esri mosaic objects are going to be invisible to map3d.  I  think I have seen solutions with oracle sdo. And I'm pretty sure you could make something work with AGS (OGC types) like WMS. someone with some knowhow will chime in probably before I get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FDO Provider for ArcSDE is based on a subset of the ArcSDE API. **This subset does not include the following:**

```
Raster functionality
Native ArcSDE metadata
The annotation data, with the exception of the ANNO_TEXT column
```

[https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Connecting-to-ArcSDE-ArcGIS-Raster.html](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting?sort=score&s=arcsde&page=1)

use WMS service as Brad Nesom mentions